# Can't connect to external API using Laravel Sail

Tags: laravel, docker-compose, laravel-sail

The project was working fine, suddenly I couldn't connection to Stripe nor Mailtrap APIs.

Stripe error

```html
Could not connect to Stripe (https://api.stripe.com/v1/setup_intents). Please check your internet connection and try again. If this problem persists, you should check Stripe's service status at https://twitter.com/stripestatus, or let us know at support@stripe.com. (Network error [errno 6]: Could not resolve host: api.stripe.com)
```

Mailtrap error

```html
Connection could not be established with host "smtp.mailtrap.io:587": stream_socket_client(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo for smtp.mailtrap.io failed: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

I tried to delete the containers and build them again with `--no-cache`

```
sail down -v
sail build --no-cache
```

But I got an error running `apt-get` commands because it can't reach to the endpoint.